# Search Folder in Directory and copy its path in new excel work book

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to develop one tool in C#.

it should b work like this.
Drive E:
In E drive there are many folder and sub folder are available , suppose i will give one folder name to that tool. it will search that folder in entire E drive and return its path in Excel work book.

I don't know how to start this work.
Please Help :(

Thanks in Advance
Sagar Trivedi

Comment: Did you consider writing tests? I would recommend writing tests for all features you want (e.g. finding a dictionary in given drive, returning its path, writing path to an excel file and so on).
When you have all your features written and working in tests try combining this into working application :)

Comment: that i dont know how to find folder in given drive.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the test that finds whether given folder name exists in the directory.

```
[TestClass]
public class DirectoryFinderTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldFindDirectoryInGivenDrive()
    {
        // Given
        var drive = "C:/";
        var folderName = "Projects";

        // When
        var finder = new DirectoryFinder();
        var result = finder.FidDirectory(drive, folderName);

        // Then
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }
}
```

The implementation is pretty simple. 
You can modify it to return path for given folder or use recurrency to search in subfolders.

```
public class DirectoryFinder
{
    public bool FidDirectory(string path, string folderName)
    {
        var directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path);
        return directories.Any(d => d.Equals(path + folderName));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain with one example pls ?